# Force power of 2 function alignment s.t alignment % some other value == alignment

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Basically I am looking for a way to force a specific relative alignment

i.e I want to gurantee that for some other value `m` s.t `m` > `n` `alignment_of(foo) % 2^m == 2^n` i.e:

```
.align 2^m;
.global foo;
.type foo, @function
foo:
// 2^n nops
// actual function start
```

but hopefully without having entry have to go through a bunch of a nops.

I need it to work with foo being linked with C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add padding before the start of the function.  The perhaps easiest way is to do something like this:

```
        .p2align m
        .byte 0xcc
        .p2align n, 0xcc
foo:    ...
```

Here, I've explicitly padded the code with `0xcc` bytes.  You can use whatever padding you like or leave out the `0xcc` to get `nop` instructions of various lengths

Comment: This spends 1..n bytes on padding, not 0..n-1 (or something like that, I'm leaving out `m`), and its worst case is when the initial address was already aligned as desired.  Unfortunately I don't think GAS (or any other assembler) has tools to do better.